# Nav bar moves position while changing page, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

My nav bar position goes down if i go to another page. How can i leave it fixed but without it staying at the top while scrolling?

```
<body>
<nav class="container-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current-page"><a href="index.html">Startpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="nieuwsberichten.html">Nieuwsberichten</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>` 


.container-nav 
{float: right;}
```

[Homepage navbar position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKTJJ.jpg)

[Niewsberichten navbar position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhcxh.jpg)

Comment: Try `.container-nav {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your problem. You want your navigation bar to always stays on top?
If so, then you could use the `position: sticky` css rule for it like that:

```html
<body>
<nav class="container-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current-page"><a href="index.html">Startpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="nieuwsberichten.html">Nieuwsberichten</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```css
.container-nav{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px; /* Or use any height you want */
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i mean i have the nav bar on the homepage and if i go to the nieuwsberichten page it goes down a inch. 

I want the nav bar at the same position on every page (top right), how can i do this?

Comment: Are there any page specific css on the  nieuwsberichten page? maybe thats causing the problem. BTW. If you change my solution to `position: fixed` from `position sticky` and add `width: 100%` to it, it should fix the issue in my opinion